# Amcharts make Guide line value dynamic with SSE

Tags: javascript, jquery, server, amcharts

im trying to add a line to amcharts like this image :

[image]

[image]
its avaliable in amcharts but only on hover ,i want to add it so it will be always there without hover , i tried to Use Am charts Guides  as following :

```js
                "guides": [{
                        "valueField":"high",                      
                          "value": this part need to be dynamic,
                          "lineAlpha": 1,
                          "lineThickness": 1,
                          "lineColor": "#fff",
                          "label": 'high'
                            }],
```

this way the line is working but it needs a value to be drawn ,the value i want it to be dynamic and changes with SERVER SENT EVENTS ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the guide after you get your server event and/or change it depending on how your app is structured. Any additions or changes to the chart properties or data require that you call the chart instance's [`validateData()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#validateData) method.

For adding a new guide (assuming regular serial chart with the guides inserted at the top level of the config):

```
chartInstance.guides.push({
  "value": /*your value here*/,
  "lineAlpha": 1,
  "lineThickness": 1,
  "lineColor": "#fff",
  "label": 'high'
});
chartInstance.validateData();
```

For updating a guide (assuming you're updating the first guide in the array):

```
//assuming you're updating the first guide in the array:
chartInstance.guides[0].value = /*new value*/
chartInstance.validateData();
```

Note that guides **don't** have a valueField. You can see a full list of properties [here](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide).

Here's a demo that adds a guide and then randomly changes the guide position every three seconds to demonstrate:

```js
function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();
  var chartData = [];
  firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 30);

  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);

    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

    var open = Math.round(Math.random() * 30 + 100);
    var close = open + Math.round(Math.random() * 15 - Math.random() * 10);

    var low;
    if (open < close) {
      low = open - Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
    } else {
      low = close - Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
    }

    var high;
    if (open < close) {
      high = close + Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
    } else {
      high = open + Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
    }

    var value = Math.round(Math.random() * 30 + 100);

    chartData[i] = {
      date: newDate,
      open: open,
      close: close,
      high: high,
      low: low,
      value: value
    };
  }
  return chartData;
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: "serial",
  theme: "black",
  dataProvider: generateChartData(),
  valueAxes: [
    {
      position: "right"
    }
  ],
  graphs: [
    {
      type: "candlestick",
      valueField: "value",
      openField: "open",
      highField: "high",
      lowField: "low",
      closeField: "close",
      lineColor: "#7f8da9",
      fillColors: "#7f8da9",
      negativeLineColor: "#db4c3c",
      negativeFillColors: "#db4c3c",
      fillAlphas: 1
    }
  ],
  categoryField: "date",
  categoryAxis: {
    parseDates: true,
    equalSpacing: true
  }
});

//simulating events using a 3 second interval
setInterval(function() {
  if (chart.guides.length) {
    chart.guides[0].value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 100);
  } else {
    chart.guides.push({
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 100),
      lineAlpha: 1,
      lineThickness: 1,
      lineColor: "#fff",
      inside: true,
      label: "high"
    });
  }
  chart.validateData();
}, 3000);
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #0d0d0d;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/black.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer which is what im looking for , but still missing only one thing , in you example u used this ;
value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 100),
so the value become (random), that what i want too but using Server sent events event.data , so when i save event data in variable and use that variable in Guide value , it get me Undefined error ,

            var source = new EventSource("live.php");
            var theGuide = "";
            source.onmessage = function(event) {
                theguide = event.data;
            };

Comment: What's undefined? Is the value getting set in some kind of AJAX setup and is sometimes undefined? You could try defaulting to 0 or something (leaving the label empty at first if you want), then updating it afterwards when you have an actual value from your event (or wait until you have a defined value before adding/updating the guide).

Comment: Note that it's really hard to troubleshoot without seeing an example. If my suggestion doesn't help, is any way you can mock up an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on jsfiddle that reproduces your setup without needing your server? You can use jsfiddle's [echo endpoints](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) to mimic AJAX requests, too.

Comment: its just and HTML5 server event , inside the function i get the value when printing the variable inside it , but when i use the variable outside the function its empty .i will try to add jsfidlle now

Comment: Sounds like you should set the value/guide inside the event and update the chart during the event instead of outside of it. Have you tried that?  I'll keep an eye out for your fiddle.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rodvynya/   , the server event is getting no response because of origin , but you can add anything inside as variable and if you try to add it to the guide value it will say undefined maybe because we are out of the scope if function , this is just demo because im using dataloader plugin instead of dataprovider and i use reload function provided in dataloader plugin .

Comment: i updated the Fiddle and allowed access origin from out of server , now you can see that on console.log i get the correct value but if i use that variabe called (theGuide) as guide value it get error message undefined

Comment: Thank you again , i was able to solve it using your method , the variable works fine using your method

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out (my apologies for not responding earlier).

Comment: Thank you again sir

Comment: The problem now is the Zoom , i was unable to preserve the Zoom after the data reload using "dataLoader": , i tried their own function but was unable to preserve zoom ,im not sure why !

Comment: Set [`zoomOutOnDataUpdate`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomOutOnDataUpdate) to false to preserve zoom after reload/updates.

Comment: Yes i was searching around and found it on a question on github , and it worked just fine , thanks again